# error while downloading zip archive from server

Tags: php, nginx

php ZipArchive can't open zip file that gets downloaded from a server.
I have a zip file that I created with winrar and uploaded to my server, file location is here: http://myserver.com/uploads/test.zip It's a valid zip file
Here is my code

When I run this code all I get is

> error: Not a zip archive.

It opens the file and extracts it but complains that file already exists even if I delete file.

the file that I get when I access http://myserver.com/update/test.zip get corrupted and I have no idea why, this same code that I pasted above worked just a week ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually the .zip file. I downloaded it and I cannot open the file with WinZip. Please try to make a new archive and upload it again on your server.

The code looks okay so I think it just the file that is the problem.

UPDATE #1:

The .zip file is now correct. Try to delete the files before you download and extract the new files. You can use unlink("uploads/update.zip") maybe you also need to clear the uploads/temp directory first.

UPDATE #2:

The download worked now for me. Try to add this header:

```
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
```

Also don't forget to close the ZipArchive after extracting:

```
$zip->close();
```

Comment: I've installed winzip my self to test the file I download from code4fun and winzip version 20.5 (12118) opens it, what version of winzip do you have?

Comment: @Maxlight I updated my answer. I am also using WinZip version 20.5 Pro.